# Google Analytics API regex to merge similar pagepaths

Tags: java, api, google-analytics

I'm querying data from the Google Analytics API and I want to merge ga:pagePathLevel1 dimensions with and without the trailing /

i.e.

I'm getting:

- g1     =     100
- g1/     =    100
- g2      =    100
- g2/     =    100

and what I need is:

- g1     =    200
- g2     =    200

Is there a way to merge both pagepaths?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create two queries and have a regex filter for each of your pagePathLevels.

filter: `ga:pagePathLevel1=~g1/?`

filter: `ga:pagePathLevel1=~g2/?`

Comment: Cheers. I did try that but there's over 250 of these entities and the URI was too long. I'll have another look at this regex you've added.